# Image texture rendered badly in Blender cycles

Tags: rendering, texturing, 3d-view, shrinkwrap

The texture looks correct in the preview but renders badly with vertical artefacts and looks very low resolution. What's going on here?

[image: Preview looks correct]

[image: The render is badly damaged]

This render, focussed on just the label (128 samples) shows the damage:

[image: Strips of vertical clipping]

Comment: It is not the texture that has poor quality, it is the whole render. You seem to be rendering at a low resolution

Comment: I rendered at 4096 samples.

Comment: That sample count seems unnecessarily high for what seems like an outdoors scene. Anyway your issue is not sample count, it is render resolution, as in pixel size of the picture

Comment: I've added a closeup on the label and simplified the node so the image texture node goes directly into a diffuse BSDF node then to the material output node.

Comment: Looking at the "750ml" part in the bottom right corner of the label the 7 and the 0 are clipped away leaving just "5ml" visible.

Comment: I have found that it happens when I add the shrinkwrap modifier.  How to stop the damage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shrinkwrap modifier must be applied first, before the subsurface modifier.

[image: Shrinkwrap at the top]

[image: Produces a better render:]

Answer (score -1):

It seems low resolution rendered image. You should check the resolution of render image. [image]

Comment: It's not related to resolution or sample count.  I've added another screenshot close up to the label.  The vertical clipping is very clear in it.